# Unable to create directory wp-content/uploads/2015/02. Is its parent directory writable by the server?

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx

I checked all the relevant permissions to groups of users do not have any problem, why is wrong?

PHP-fpm users and user groups is nginx
Nginx users and user groups is nginx
WP-content user group is the highest of all permissions

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

1. go to www.your-domain.com/your-wp-dir/wp-admin/options.php
2. find option uploads_use_yearmonth_folders
3. set value to 1

Answer (score 0):

This issue is related to paths

Go to DASHBOARD > MISCELLANEOUS > UPLOADING FILES and check the path to see if it is correct

Answer (score 0):

Check 
uploads_use_yearmonth_folders   
and 
upload_path 
in wp-admin/options.php
and verify that upload_path is correct
may be this one helps

Answer (score 0):

This type of issue basically they are just clone or transferred to a new domain name or some other locations, so their media settings in uploading files were affected.

Here's my solution for this:
On your **WP Dashboard** go-to **Settings** then **Media** and check your **Uploading Files** then look for this section "**Store uploads in this folder**", mostly this will be affected if you just clone the old domain to a new domain-name, change the path where your domain-name is located. You can check this using **Cpanel** then using **File Manager**, if you are familiar using this then you know what i'm saying :)

Please see screenshot below for more details regarding to Media Settings in Wordpress.

[Media Settings -screenshot-](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BmTnS.jpg)